# How to display a list of names inside a DIV in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically,

I'm working on a project and let's say I have a list of people:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>() {
    {"James"}, {"Harry"}
};
```

These are generated in the CodeBehind.cs page. My question is: In the asp.net page, how would I then return this list and display all the names inside a div?

Comment: you shouldn't use session for this process. You can use literal control to do this.

Comment: @user990513 Please could you provide an example? Would there be a foreach loop or something?

Comment: Your question title is totally misleading !!!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, still you need to think how quickly you could change the UI template.

The below two approach will give a control of HTML in aspx page, which is easy compared to generating those in a code behind.

1. Use [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ListView](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui) control and bind your list to it
2. Render into UI directly with the below code

In Codebehind

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 public List<string> name;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   name=//load your list here
 }
}
```

In aspx

```
<div>
<%
 foreach(string str in name)
 {%>
 <span><%= str %> </span>
 <%}
%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a `div`, and place a `LiteralControl` inside it

```
<div>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

and in code-behind

```
List<string> name = new List<string>() {
                     {"James"}, {"Harry"}
            };

    Literal1.Text = "<ul>";
    foreach (var n in name)
    {
        Literal1.Text += "<li>"+n+"</li>";

    }
    Literal1.Text += "</ul>";
```

Comment: This will just concatenate all the names - I don't think that is what the OP is after.

Comment: @Rune: he want to display list in asp page

Comment: Yes, and your code will display "JamesHarry". Does that seem right to you?

Comment: @AmitKumar not the downvoter, but why you don't bother yourself with formatting? Is it that hard?

Comment: @Fyodor: I accept it. but just because of not well formatted , one can downvote .

Comment: @AmitKumar I think that this downvote is not because of formatting (I was just curios)

Comment: @AmitKumar downvoter might argue that you should really use the view engine for rendering HTML instead of piecing HTML together in C#. If you do want to build HTML in C#, using a StringBuilder or an HtmlTextWriter might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It will be solution for your question

Code-behind:

```
string s = string.Emtpy;
foreach (var item in l)
{
    s += item + "<br/>"
}

LiteralName.Text = s;
```

Comment: or <div runat="server" id="divName"></div> code behind : div.InnerHtml=s;